# Discord oauth2 /users/@me/guilds error 401

Tags: javascript, discord, authorization

It is supposed to get all the guilds a user is joined in. It gets the bearer auth right, but it always errors with code 401. When using a external API (https://reqbin.com/) with auth to test the discord API  it also gives the same error 401.

This is the code:

```
    let discordCode = window.location.href
    let code = discordCode.split("?code=")
    if(code && code.length > 0){
        discordCode = code[code.length-1]
    }

    console.log(discordCode)

    fetch("https://discord.com/api/users/@me/guilds",{method: 'GET',headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer  ${discordCode}`,
    }}).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    })

    /*fetch(`/discordProxy/${discordCode}`).then(function(response) {
        response.json().then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    })*/

    $("#connect_top_button").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=955915443405729844&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F130.162.37.209%2Fservers&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds"
    })
```

The oauth2 scopes I gave to the app are: identify, email, guilds

Edit: Actually, it seems that all the auth tokens from the oauth2 don't work. Weird

Comment: Maybe I don't understand this well, however I redirect the user to 
https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=955915443405729844&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F130.162.37.209%2Fservers&response_type=code&scope=identify%20guilds
And read from window.location.href the code, however that code always just doesn't work either with my code or with a external API tester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get discord token and use it in authorization:

```
"Authorization": `Bearer  ${await getTokenDiscord()}`
```

here is my example of getting the discord token:

```
async getTokenDiscord() {
    const params = new URLSearchParams()
    params.append('client_id', CLIENT_ID)
    params.append('client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET)
    params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code')
    params.append('code', YOUR_DISCORD_CODE)
    params.append('redirect_uri', REDIRECT_URL)
    params.append('scope', 'identify')

    const resp = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
      method: 'post',
      body: params,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    })

    return await resp.json()
}
```

It's not the best example of how to do this, but it's the way it works for me